# UIDatePicker - Day picker reference

Tags: ios, accessibility, uidatepicker

I am integrating an iOS app with Accessibility. I have to put the focus on the Day-picker of an UIDatePicker, but I don't find a reference to that "subpicker". If you guys could help me with this, I would be grateful.

Thanks!